# Application is unable to do a Bulk Insert . Operating system error code 5 (Access Denied)

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy

we are trying to upload record in database using .csv file in 3 tier architecture using sql database stored procedure.

Application server Jboss 6.4
Sql Server
Web server IIS
.CSV in Shared san storage Server which is separate

All access provided to share san storage folder, Bulk admin rights given to sql user

Using Windows authentication and AD authentication on servers with service account.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You need to provide all the details and 
mention the issue clearly what exactly you want. Please refer the
[ask] link for more detail and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I agree with @JeroenHeier. In my experience, though, I've had this error when I forgot I still had the file open in a text editor.

Comment: I would try checking if the SQL user has access to the (remote?) file. Try to deploy the input file within the same machine the DB is running (some tempo folder) and attempt running your program. I've face this issue in the past and had something to do with accessing a file located on a network drive.

Comment: Issue Resolution -  ​Added particular san storage  server account to UAC and provide local administrator access.